# Problem with while loop and not getting the expected output?

Tags: java, while-loop

This is a Java question and which I have a problem with the while loop. The program must allow the customer to enter the number of liters of petrol they wish to purchase and the liter value is $1.75. Then, for each
liter of petrol up to the quantity that the customer has entered, the program must display a
running total.

and this is the expected output and which I am not getting

```
Please Enter the Litres of Petrol (a whole number): 20
Litre 0: $0.0
Litre 1: $1.75
Litre 2: $3.5
...
Litre 19: $33.25
Litre 20: $35.0
```

and this is my code so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System. in );
    int numOfLiter;

    System.out.println("Please enter the liters of Petrol: ");
    numOfLiter = kb.nextInt();

    double pricePerLitre = 1.75;
    int count = 0;

    while (count <= 10) {
        Double total = pricePerLitre + count;
        System.out.println("Liter " + count + ": " + total);

        count++;

    }
}
```

Comment: Also, you should loop on `count < numOfLiter`, not on `count <= 10`

Comment: I think you mixed up `total = total + priceperlitre` and `total = count * priceperlitre`. Voting to close as a simple typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your output, your while loop should loop till the input provided i.e `numOfLiter`

```
int count = 0;

while (count <= numOfLiter) {
    Double total = pricePerLitre * count;
    System.out.println("Liter " + count + ": " + total);

    count++;
}
```

And, also

```
Double total = pricePerLitre + count
```

should be

```
Double total = pricePerLitre * count
```

Comment: Shouldn't count be declared to 1?

Comment: @NicholasK can be, but OP expected output is `Litre 0: $0.0`.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps a lot

Comment: Yeah, missed that - noted that in my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `for-loop` to achieve the same.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System. in );
    int numOfLiter;

    System.out.println("Please enter the liters of Petrol: ");
    numOfLiter = kb.nextInt();

    double pricePerLitre = 1.75;

    for (int i = 0; i <= numOfLiter; i++) {
        Double total = pricePerLitre * i;
        System.out.println("Liter " + i + ": " + total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Double total = pricePerLitre * count;
```

Instead of :

```
Double total = pricePerLitre + count;
```

In your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the liters of Petrol: ");
    int numOfLiter = kb.nextInt();
    double pricePerLitre = 1.75;
    IntStream.range(0, numOfLiter + 1).forEach(i ->  System.out.println("Liter " + i  + ": " + i* pricePerLitre));
}
```

But in real code better use BigDecimal